# SQL Query in StarcounterDB

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query problem in my Starcounter database where I want to write a query that retrieves html pages (Content) containing a specific set of keywords based on the following models.

```
class Keyword {
   int Id;
   string Text;
}
```

Example data:
Id       Text
1 google
2 advertising
3 twitter

```
class Content {
   int Id;
   string Text;
}
```

Example data:
Id       Text
4 "google advertising is nice for marketers"
5 "twitter is not a good way to get exposure"

```
class HasWord : Relation {
   Keyword Keyword;
   Content Content;
}
```

Example data:
Keyword       Content
1 4
2 4
3 5

How would I write a Query that retrieves all Content containing 2 specific words, in this case "google" and "advertising"? Is it possible without nested queries?

Input:
"google" & "advertising"

Desired output:

"google advertising is nice for marketers"

Comment: Can you give us an example? Like how the table should look like and the output that you want should look like

Comment: Do you have an interview? or you work for a company and you need to do this job?

Comment: Do you mean `Content.Text` contains the words or `Keyword` in relation with `Content` has keywords as the words or `Text` in either `Content` or `Keyword` contains the words? It looks like your request can be written as single query with disjunction (`OR`) in the where clause.

Comment: Content.Text containing the words. You are correct that it can be done with a single query with OR like this: 

SELECT Content FROM HasWord WHERE Keyword.Text = 'google' OR Keyword.Text = 'advertising'

But that returns a result if just one of the words match - I need both of the words to match. Something like this:

SELECT Content FROM HasWord WHERE Keyword.Text = 'google' AND Keyword.Text = 'advertising'

Which doesn't work though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to find an instance of `Content` , which `Text` contains both words, then you can use operator `LIKE` with regular expression, which is described [here](https://github.com/Starcounter/Starcounter/wiki/SQL-Comparison-Predicates). For example:

```
    SELECT Text 
    FROM Content 
    WHERE Text LIKE '%google%' AND Text LIKE '%advertising%'
```

If you need to find an instance of `Content`, which is in relationship with both keywords, then you can use self-join. For example

```
    SELECT r1.Content.Text
    FROM HasWord r1, HasWord r2
    WHERE r1.Content = r2.Content AND
        r1.Keyword.Text = 'google' AND r2.Keyword.Text = 'advertising'
```

Note that the result of the query will contain duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, the second alternative did it!